# Java Stream for JSONArray

Tags: java, json, java-8, java-stream

I have JSONArray and wanted to use stream to iterate them, any alternative approach to the below traditional way,

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    methodCall(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
 }
```

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite, how and what did you try?

Comment: for(Object o: arr){
    if ( o instanceof JSONObject ) {
        parse((JSONObject)o);
    }
}

Comment: this is one way i tried but using spilitator we can but it's collecting object.

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, jsonArray.length()).mapToObj(jsonArray::getJSONObject) …`

Comment: Thanks guys, i follow the https://www.techiedelight.com/iterate-over-stream-indices-java8/ approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the 2 steps that are

- `jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)` you need the result of this so use a `map()` operation
- `methodCall()` this is a terminal operation (no need of the result) so use a `forEach()` operation

```
IntStream.range(0, jsonArray.length()).mapToObj(jsonArray::getJSONObject)
                                      .forEach(Myclass:methodCall)
```